# react-native run-android on Android < 5

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

i'm trying to run an Android App on a simulator with Android V4.1.1,
the app is working ok in Android version > 5, but when i try to run the app on Android V4.X the terminal is giving me the next error:

```
Running adb -s xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5555 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
error: closed
Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: adb -s xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:5555 reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

After showing that error the app shows:

```
Unfortunately, APP_NAME has stopped.
```

I have the latest version of the Android SDK and tools.

Comment: I am also interested in solution of this problem. As it says here http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.22/docs/running-on-device-android.html#using-adb-reverse, adb reverse is available on devices running android 5.0+ . And without this command I wasn't able to run app in Debug mode...

Comment: Have you tried configuring your dev build to connect over WiFi? As per https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#debugging-on-a-device-with-chrome-developer-tools
"Alternatively, select "Dev Settings" from the Developer Menu, then update the "Debug server host for device" setting to match the IP address of your computer."

Comment: `adb reverse` command is not supported in android < 5

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to run in Android 4.1.1, in Genymotion it wasn't working, but in the simulator of Android Studio it works. I still can't manage to make it run on Geny.