# Adb command similar to reverse?

Tags: android, react-native, adb

I used to run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081` to connect/reconnect my devices to react native development server. but it's not supported on android 5. since adb reverse not supported on android <5x. i need it to do test app in old android version
also i cant connect the device to react native server via wi-fi because it is an emulator

is there any similar command to do this?

Comment: Did you check these answers:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44378329/react-native-run-android-on-android-5

Answer (score 0):

Connect via Wi-Fi

You can also connect to the development server over Wi-Fi. You'll first need to install the app on your device using a USB cable, but once that has been done you can debug wirelessly by following these instructions. You'll need your development machine's current IP address before proceeding.

You can find the IP address in System Preferences → Network.

Make sure your laptop and your phone are on the same Wi-Fi network. Open your React Native app on your device. You'll see a red screen with an error. This is OK. The following steps will fix that. Open the in-app Developer menu. Go to Dev Settings → Debug server host for device. Type in your machine's IP address and the port of the local dev server (e.g. 10.0.1.1:8081). Go back to the Developer menu and select Reload JS.