# How to connect react native app with backend django

Tags: django, react-native, android-studio

So I have a backend with django and I am using react native for frontend. I added a emulator in android studio.

And when I start the backend like: python manage.py runserver I can run also the frontend with expo start.

But now I want to fetch the data with react native. So I start the backend with:
python manage.py runserver  192.168.1.68:19000 - settings file of django:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
    'DierenWelzijnAdmin.apps.DierenwelzijnadminConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.68', '127.0.0.1', ]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = False
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    "http://localhost:8081",
    "http://localhost:19006",
    "http://localhost:19002",
    "http://192.168.1.69:8000",
    "http://192.168.1.68:19000",
]

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
]
```

And react native service:

```
export const fetchCategoryData = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch("http://192.168.1.68:19000/animal/categories/main_groups/", {
            method: "GET",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json",
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
        });
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
        }

        return await response.json();
        //setCategoryData(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("There was a problem with the fetch operation:", error);
        throw error;
    }
};
```

And when I then start the react native app with expo start and I do a r after a.

I get this message:

```
warn No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB.
```

The emulator I installed from android studio is: Pixel 2 XL and if I do: adb devices
I see the emulator:

```
List of devices attached
emulator-5554   device
```

And I already whiped the data several times from the emulator.

Question:

How to run the react native for fetching data from the backend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No apps connected. Sending "reload" to all React Native apps failed. Make sure your app is running in the simulator or on a phone connected via USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62937553/no-apps-connected-sending-reload-to-all-react-native-apps-failed-make-sure-y)

Comment: But I am running on a emulator with android

Comment: Check the provided link for all available answers; there is an issue with your IP. I think your emulator is not able to connect to the provided IP.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari. But the ip is correct: I did a ipconfig:   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::3a4e:7938:aa45:3ef%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.68
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Comment: @AnkitTiwari. And if I start the backend and go to: http://192.168.1.68:19000/animal/categories/main_groups/ the api call works.

Comment: If you've access to `adb` command [`adb reverse tcp:9000 tcp:9000`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062291/adb-command-similar-to-reverse) this tells you emulator to listen port 9000 on your computer

Comment: @AnkitTiwari. So you mean port 19000 in this case?  adb reverse tcp:19000 tcp:19000

Comment: Yes, change it to 19000

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251834/discussion-between-mightycode-newton-and-ankit-tiwari).

Comment: @AnkitTiwari. Oke, I did  adb reverse tcp:19000 tcp:19000 and after expo start. And that worked. But if I do now expo start... same error

Comment: I think instead of adb you've to look for expo command to connect you computer port inside your emulator. In order to connect your emulator to your computer you've to open ports from both side from your computer as well as your  emulator

Comment: Oke, I changed the backend to: http://192.168.1.68:8000 and in frontend also: http://192.168.1.68:8000. and it works now :)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari. Maybe you have an idea about this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75445372/calling-property-of-api-conext-error-element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-strin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke, I changed the backend to:

> 192.168.1.68:8000

`and in frontend also:`

> 192.168.1.68:8000

and it works now :)

This was indeed very stupid of me. Because I did fetch('//192.168.1.68:19000'). But that is my emulator host. Of course that doesn't work